# Check for duplicate user account and email address

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to check to see if a username or email address already existed in my database. I can currently connect to my database and retrieve data from my registering form. However, my SQL statements are not able to check my database to see if the user exists or not. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
<?php

require 'database.php';
$conn = Connect();

if ($conn == true){
   echo "Successfully connected to database. <br><br>";}

   $username      = $_POST['screenname'];
   $password      = $_POST['password'];
   $email         = $_POST['email'];

   echo "$username<br>"; //just checkin if it can grab data
   echo "$password<br>";
   echo "$email<br>";


   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE screenname = '$username'");

   if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
    {
        echo "Username already exists";
    }
   else
    {
        //insert query goes here
    }


   $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

   if(mysql_num_rows($sql2)>=1)
     {
        echo "Email already exists";
     }
        else
     {
          //insert query
     }


    ?>
```

Comment: looks fine, what part is not working?

Comment: thats what i thought too, when I enter the same username for registration it does not hit that if statement and echo if the username exists.. it just does nothing.

Comment: If you want, you can first echo the result of `mysql_num_rows`, to check whether it shows what you really expect

Comment: i added an echo statement inside the first if statement, it didn't echo anything so I assume it's not even hitting the if statement

Comment: ok, the thing is, you're probably looking for a LIKE statement instead of a equal. try that.

Comment: `$conn` is a `mysql_*` connection? You shouldn't use `mysql_` anymore. Do you get an errors with this code? You also are open to SQL injections. What if the screenname where an email, or vice versa, is that allowed?

Comment: @chris85 `Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis, thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator`. Without the wildcards (% and _) LIKE and = are similar

Comment: Yes the like statement is not what I need, I need to check for an exact match of the username so there is not duplicates. I get no errors with this code, it connects to the DB fine and also gets the username, password, and email that the user enters on the register page.

Comment: @chris85 he's building the query with user input, escaping characters shouldn't be a priority here xD. just try it with like instead and check the results.

Comment: @LordNeo Hahaha, Good luck to you and the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Logic, programming and security (SQL injection attack) bugs fixed:

```
<?php

require 'database.php';
$conn = Connect();

if ($conn == true){
    echo "Successfully connected to database. <br><br>";
}

$username      = $_POST['screenname'];
$password      = $_POST['password'];
$email         = $_POST['email'];

echo "$username<br>"; //just checkin if it can grab data
echo "$password<br>";
echo "$email<br>";


$sql= sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE screenname='%s' OR email='%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($username),
        mysql_real_escape_string($email)
    );

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
{
    echo "Username or e-mail already exists";
}
else
{
    //insert query goes here
}
```

Comment: Also you should learn Object Programming, it's 2017! PHP MySQL connection using object: PDO! https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_connect.asp